# Convert binary tree to store in array

Tags: arrays, data-structures, binary-tree

So I've been researching binary trees, and I was wondering what standard system would you use to to convert a binary tree to be stored in an array? So it would be a system which would make sure that no 2 nodes of the tree map to the same index of the array.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-array-implementation/#:~:text=Talking%20about%20representation%2C%20trees%20can%20be%20represented%20in%20two%20way%3A&text=To%20represent%20tree%20using%20an,1)%20or%201%E2%80%93%20n.

Comment: @AkshayBande Thank you, but I'm unsure as to how i justify why it is correct so why it guarantees that no two nodes of the tree map to the same index of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In binary tree each node will have two children, we can use this property to represent it using an array.

In array representation there will be some empty indexes, if tree is not complete binary tree.

If array is 1 based index then every node has its left child at pos 2*i and right child at position 2*i + 1.

For 0 based indexed, left child is located at 2*i+1 and right child at 2*i+2.

Because of left and right indexes are calculated in this manner it won't overlap.

[For more information about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays)